# Rails & Heroku | Stripe::AuthenticationError (No API key provided)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm getting this error when I try to process a payment but I can't see where I'm going wrong:

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['stripe_publishable_key'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['stripe_api_key']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

application.yml (figaro):

```
production:
  stripe_api_key: XXXXXX
  stripe_publishable_key: XXXXXX
```

And then I run "figaro heroku:set -e production" and I get the success message showing all the correct set keys.

What am I missing?

EDIT: added heroku dashboard screenshot

[image]

Comment: Would you mind including screenshot of the Heroku website admin panel where the environment variables are shown. Just color the actual values out before doing it.

Comment: @sanfor added a screenshot to OP

Comment: Hmm, everything seems to be in place and the environment variable seems legit. Have you checked Heroku's logs with `heroku logs` for any problems during start-up?

Comment: can you show the code where you are calling for the api key

Answer (score 0):

In your stripe.rb file the last line should be looking for [:stripe_api_key]  not [:secret_key]  so it should be:

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:stripe_api_key]
```

Change that and it should work.

(I know this is an old question, but I wanted to answer it as it comes up in searches for this topic).

Note - it Rails 5.2 the file would look like this now:

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_publishable_key],    
  :secret_key => Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]    
}    
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]
```

Just make sure the key names (ie [:stripe_publishable_key] match the names inside your credentials.yml.enc file.  In my case I added stripe to each of them so it's clear which publishable and private key I'm looking for.. but that's just me :)

My credintials.yml.enc file looks like this:

```
stripe:
  stripe_secret_key: sk_blahblahblah
  stripe_publishable_key: pk_blahblahblah
```

Hope this helps others in the future.